# Issue connecting components to Auto-IVC in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to connect the optimization parameter defined in **Auto-IVC** to a different **MDAO** component, with

```
p.model.connect('_auto_ivc.my_parameter','my_component.other_parameter')
```

and I am getting the following error:

> NameError:  : Attempted to connect from
> '_auto_ivc.traj.parameters:exoatmos_a_t_duration' to
> 'traj.phases.exoatmos_a.t_duration', but
> '_auto_ivc.traj.parameters:exoatmos_a_t_duration' doesn't exist.

This issue arose from upgrading from **OpenMDAO 3.1.0 to 3.11.0.**

Comment: It seems as though you're using dymos, and I'm guessing you're trying to make the duration of the phase be linked to a parameter.

If you specify `input_duration=True`, then `t_duration` _will_ be a parameter to your phase that you can change using the path `traj.phase_name.t_duration`.

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I am using Dymos indeed and I am trying to make the duration of a phase be linked to a parameter. I already specified `input_duration=True` when defining the phase, and now I want to connect this phase duration to a parameter (formerly design parameter in previous Dymos versions, now defined as a parameter with `opt=True`) I previously defined in the trajectory. 
Before the new updated versions, I knew how to do it and connect the phase duration to a design parameter. Now, I can't, since I have to use the Auto-IVC component and don't know how to find the path to my parameter.

Comment: You can use `t_duration_targets` in the time options to pass t_duration to some input in the ODE.

Comment: We tried what was suggested, but it still encounters problems. In this case we had created a parameter to serve as the new t_duration. When we tried to pass this parameter as the new t_duration for a phase with `t_duration_targets` in the time options, it tries to connect not to the parameter we created but to some in `rhs_col` and it says that `t_duration` is an input. Looking at the n2 file, our parameter is defined in the Auto_ivc section, so it does not allow us to connect it in this way. In the old version we had no problems with this, but now the connections' definition is different.

Comment: OK this sounds like a possible bug.  I'd be happy to take a look at it, but please file an issue at https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos

Comment: Still regarding this issue, the bug has been corrected and the error with the `rhs_col` disappeared, but we still cannot connect the parameter we created to the duration of the phase. `input_duration=True` was specified when defining the phase and now the error displayed mentions that both of the objects we are trying to connect are inputs. We were not able to do it, so do you have any advice on what should be the best way to proceed? As mentioned above, we want to use a design parameter we created as the new `t_duration` of a phase.

Comment: In OpenMDAO it is not allowed to connect an input to an input, you have to connect an output to an input.

There are two ways around this.

1. In general in OpenMDAO, you promote both variables to the same name.

2. For dymos specifically you can connect `<phase_path>.timeseries.time_phase` from the end of one phase (`indices=[-1]`) to the `t_duration` input.

Comment: With the number 2, the error now is "Output and input are in the same System for connection". I think we used a bad practice for the code from the start, because before the upgrade to the new version we achieved what we wanted with `traj.connect('design_parameters:<parameter_name>', '<phase_name>.t_duration')`. The parameter was defined in the same script and the phase as well. For the new version, ´design_parameters` becomes `parameters` with `opt=True` when defining it, but the above line is not possible anymore.

Comment: I think your confusion is that you're using the parameter as a source for t_duration.  Instead, use `t_duration_targets` in the time options to tell dymos the targets in the ODE that should accept the value of `t_duration`.  `t_duration` and `t_initial` are basically two "special" parameters.